# SEVERE: Servlet threw load() exception javax.servlet.UnavailableException

Tags: spring, jakarta-ee, tomcat, servlets, struts

I am getting the below error while deploying my application in Tomcat 6.0.26 on eclipse Juno. I am using struts for web content and spring for ORM.

I have tried cleaning up and building up the Workspace.

```
Mar 19, 2013 5:33:30 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin
WARNING: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:CPCPROJ' did not find a matching property.
Mar 19, 2013 5:33:30 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init
INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_18\bin;.;C:\WINDOWS\Sun\Java\bin;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_18\jre\bin;C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.6.0_18/bin/../jre/bin/client;C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.6.0_18/bin/../jre/bin;C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.6.0_18/bin/../jre/lib/i386;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_18\bin;E:\Oracle\product\10.1.0\Client_2\bin;E:\Oracle\product\10.1.0\Client_2\jre\1.4.2\bin\client;E:\Oracle\product\10.1.0\Client_2\jre\1.4.2\bin;E:\Oracle\product\10.1.0\Client_1\bin;E:\Oracle\product\10.1.0\Client_1\jre\1.4.2\bin\client;E:\Oracle\product\10.1.0\Client_1\jre\1.4.2\bin;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0;C:\Program Files\Windows Imaging\;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_18\bin;E:\456789\Venkat\Servers\Tomcat\bin;E:\456789\Venkat\Servers\JBoss\bin;E:\apache-maven-2.2.1\bin;E:\456789\Venkat\Servers\apache-ant-1.7.0\bin;.;C:\Documents and Settings\456789\My Documents\Downloads\eclipse-jee-kepler-M4-win32\eclipse;
Mar 19, 2013 5:33:30 PM org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol init
INFO: Initializing Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-8080
Mar 19, 2013 5:33:30 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 769 ms
Mar 19, 2013 5:33:30 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService start
INFO: Starting service Catalina
Mar 19, 2013 5:33:30 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine start
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/6.0.20
Mar 19, 2013 5:33:31 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader validateJarFile
INFO: validateJarFile(E:\356387\Venkat\Juno\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\CPCPROJ\WEB-INF\lib\j2ee-1.4.jar) - jar not loaded. See Servlet Spec 2.3, section 9.7.2. Offending class: javax/servlet/Servlet.class
Mar 19, 2013 5:33:31 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader validateJarFile
INFO: validateJarFile(E:\356387\Venkat\Juno\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\CPCPROJ\WEB-INF\lib\servlet-api.jar) - jar not loaded. See Servlet Spec 2.3, section 9.7.2. Offending class: javax/servlet/Servlet.class
Mar 19, 2013 5:33:32 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Initializing Spring root WebApplicationContext
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (com.tcs.framework.configuration.TCSCommonsConfigurationFactory).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
Mar 19, 2013 5:33:43 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Marking servlet action as unavailable
Mar 19, 2013 5:33:43 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext loadOnStartup
SEVERE: Servlet /CPCPROJ threw load() exception
javax.servlet.UnavailableException
    at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.init(ActionServlet.java:402)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:212)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1173)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:993)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:4149)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4458)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1045)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.start(StandardHost.java:722)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1045)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.start(StandardEngine.java:443)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.start(StandardService.java:516)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:710)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:583)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:288)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:413)
Mar 19, 2013 5:33:44 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Initializing Spring FrameworkServlet 'CPCPROJ'
Mar 19, 2013 5:33:47 PM org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol start
INFO: Starting Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-8080
Mar 19, 2013 5:33:47 PM org.apache.jk.common.ChannelSocket init
INFO: JK: ajp13 listening on /0.0.0.0:8009
Mar 19, 2013 5:33:47 PM org.apache.jk.server.JkMain start
INFO: Jk running ID=0 time=0/31  config=null
Mar 19, 2013 5:33:47 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 16435 ms
```

Answer (score -1):

I think the data you provided in web.xml is not proper please check it once.

[see here](http://connecttoatul.wordpress.com/2010/06/16/error-404-javax-servlet-unavailableexception-srve0203e-servlet-servletverify/)  for details

Comment: Is the below entry in top of web.xml is wrong? <web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">